# Deactivate weekends on datepicker by clicking on a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I try to write some lists of JavaScript code to but now stuck on a problem with the datepicker. The goal is: when the 'Only during working days' checkbox is checked, the weekend dates (Saturday and Sunday) on datepicker must be deactivated. I tried, but so far it didnt work. Here is my HTML and JavaScript code. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

```js
$(function() {

      $( "#weekday" ).click(function() {
        if ($(this).is('checked')) {
          $("#startdate").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            dateFormat: "dd'.'mm'.'yy",
            firstDay: 1,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
          })

          $("#enddate").datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
            dateFormat: "dd'.'mm'.'yy",
            firstDay: 1,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
          })
        } else {

          $("#startdate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd'.'mm'.'yy",
            firstDay: 1,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
          })

          $("#enddate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd'.'mm'.'yy",
            firstDay: 1,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true
          })

        }

      })
    })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="weekday" name="weekday" value="weekday">
  <label for="weekday">Only during working days</label><br>
  <p>Start Date: <br><input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate"></p>
  <p>End Date: <br><input type ="text" id="enddate" name="enddate"></p>
  <p>Quantity: <br><input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity"><br></p>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- don’t use `click` events on checkboxes, use `change`
- `if ($(this).is('checked')) {` - it’s `is(':checked')`
- don’t initialize the date pickers inside the checkbox handler, initialize them separately from that
- don’t re-initialize them, use the `option` method to change specific settings instead

```js
$(function() {

  $("#startdate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd'.'mm'.'yy",
    firstDay: 1,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true
  })

  $("#enddate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd'.'mm'.'yy",
    firstDay: 1,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true
  })

  $("#weekday").change(function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#startdate, #enddate").datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', $.datepicker.noWeekends)
      } else {
        $("#startdate, #enddate").datepicker('option', 'beforeShowDay', null)
      }
    })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="weekday" name="weekday" value="weekday">
  <label for="weekday">Only during working days</label><br>
  <p>Start Date: <br><input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate"></p>
  <p>End Date: <br><input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate"></p>
  <p>Quantity: <br><input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity"><br></p>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</body>
```